# How to convert arrays in to XML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a array with multiple elements in it :

```
var arrayData = [
  customerId: "123", mobileNumber: "999"},
  customerId: "122", mobileNumber: "998"},
  customerId: "121", mobileNumber: "997"}
];
```

I need this to convert into XML like below:

```
<Result> 
    <customerId>123</customerId>
    <mobileNumber1>999</mobileNumber>
    <customerId>122</customerId>
    <mobileNumber1>998</mobileNumber>
    <customerId>121</customerId>
    <mobileNumber1>997</mobileNumber>
</Result>
```

I've tried the following:

```
arrayData.map(obj => `<Result><customerId>${obj.customerId}</customerId><mobileNumber>${obj.mobileNumber}</mobileNumber></Result>`).join('');
```

but I'm getting unavailable in placeholders , any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is it working, besides you have invalid code

```js
var arrayData = [
  {customerId: "123", mobileNumber: "999"},
  {customerId: "122", mobileNumber: "998"},
  {customerId: "121", mobileNumber: "997"}
];

console.log("<Result>" + arrayData.map(obj => `<customerId>${obj.customerId}</customerId><mobileNumber>${obj.mobileNumber}</mobileNumber>`).join('') + "</Result>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not map your `<Result>` over and over again. You can concat it

```js
let arrayData = [
{customerId: "123", mobileNumber: "999"},
{customerId: "122", mobileNumber: "998"},
{customerId: "121", mobileNumber: "997"}
]


let result = "<Result>" + arrayData.map(obj => `<customerId>${obj.customerId}</customerId><mobileNumber>${obj.mobileNumber}</mobileNumber>`).join("") + "</Result>";

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

More functional programming approach, `reduce` is a very powerful function.

```
arrayData.reduce((acc, curr, index, src) => {    
    const customerId = `<customerId>${curr.customerId}</customerId>`
    const mobile = `<mobileNumber>${curr.mobileNumber}</mobileNumber>`
    acc = acc + `${customerId}${mobile}`    
    if(src.length - 1 === index) {
        acc = `<Result>${acc}</Result>`
    }
    return acc;
}, '')
```